# Prove that the ring of rational numbers $\Bbb Q$ is not isomorphic to the ring of real numbers $\Bbb R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-verification

just wondering if my reasoning is correct. 
I said assume there is such a homomorphism f, then f(1)=1 since it is a ring homomorphism. But

$$f(\sqrt 2)= f(1\cdot\sqrt 2)= f(1) \cdot \sqrt 2= \sqrt 2$$

but $\sqrt 2$ is not a rational, contradiction. Is the proof this simple or am i missing something? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isomorphisms are bijections. $\Bbb Q$ is countable and $\Bbb R$ is not.

Comment: Right I know that, but I was wondering if my proof shows that there isn't even a homomorphism between the two much less a bijective one?

Comment: @joe There is exactly one ringhomomorphism $\mathbb Q\rightarrow R$ wich is the map $x\mapsto x$. It is not surjective so is not an isomorphism.

Comment: @AdamHughes, $\mathbb Q$ is not an $\mathbb R$-module in any way: there is no such thing as «trivially» in this context.

Comment: Oh right, because of the copy of $\Bbb Q$ inside $\Bbb R$, duh. It cannot be done with $\Bbb Q$ keeping it's canonical structure; clearly I need to have my morning coffee. Thanks. @_@

Comment: I don't think the second equality in your statement actually holds here. Is that what other users are contesting - but in a way that I don't understand?

Answer (score 7):

No, that reasoning is not correct, but it is almost correct. $\sqrt{2}$ doesn't mean anything in a general ring.

I will subscript things with $_q$ for rationals an $_r$ for reals when something is ambiguous. So $2_q$ is the rational number $2$, while $2_r$ is the real number.

$$2_q=1_q+1_q=f(1_r)+f(1_r)=f(2_r)=f(\sqrt{2}\cdot \sqrt{2})=f(\sqrt{2})\cdot f(\sqrt{2})$$

So $f(\sqrt{2})$ would have to be a rational number whose square is $2$, which is impossible.

This is not the same as saying $f(\sqrt{2})=\sqrt{f(2)}$, because square root is not a function on $\mathbb Q$, so it doesn't actually mean anything.

Comment: Thanks, i get your proof but why for mine do you say that sqrt2 does not mean anything in a general ring? Doesn't it mean the number such that when you square it you get 2. And since Q has no such element, then contradiction?

Comment: @joe yes, but you're presupposing that such a thing exists, using that symbol. For $f$ to be a function it needs to be *well-defined*, so that the output is actually a thing in the target.

Comment: @joe Because there might not be such a thing in a general ring. It is undefined unless there is such a thing. (It is also ambiguous - not all rings are order, so you can't distinguish a "positive" square root of two from a "negative" one, so $\sqrt{2}$ has to represent multiple values. (It can even be more than $2$ in some rings.)

Comment: For example, in the integers modulo $119=7\cdot 17$, there are four square roots of $2$.

Comment: Adam Hughes, I don't believe I'm presupposing anything though, I'm just following the requirement that for any homomorphism f(ab)= f(a)f(b), which means f(1*sqrt2)= f(1)*sqrt(2)= sqrt2? In other words, since f has to act on every element of R, then for f(sqrt2), it must send it somewhere? And it happens to be to sqrt2 which does not exist.

Comment: Thomas Andrews, thanks, but knowing before hand that Q has no square roots, can't I make the claim I'm making? I know it's cheating a little.

Comment: @joe Perhaps you are not presupposing it yourself, but mathematicians will read this as presupposing that $\sqrt{2}$ exists. You haven't actually shown why $f(\sqrt{2})=\sqrt{2}$, which you've just asserted. $Q$ does have square roots, just not for all elements. You can't say $f(\sqrt 2)=\sqrt{2}$ unless you've defined this in a very careful and confusing way. There are rings $R$ with automorphisms $h:R\to R$ which send one square root of two to another. Writing this as $h(\sqrt{2})=\sqrt{2}$ would be terribly confusing.

Comment: @joe yes you are, how do you go from $f(\sqrt 2)=f(1)f(\sqrt{2})$ to $f(1)\cdot\sqrt 2$? Where has your $f$ gone?

Comment: just using the fact that f(sqrt2)= f(1*sqrt2)= sqrt2*f(1)?

Comment: oh wow I just checked the  definitions of homomorphisms, I can NOT do that. Sorry for the dumb moment! Thanks for all the help everyone.

Comment: @joe you probably have seen $f(nx)=nf(x)$ when $n$ is an integer. This is true, but here, $nx$ is defined not as mutliplication, but as repeated sum of $n$ Values of $x$ (At least when $n>0$. When $n<0$, you have to define it as $-((-n)x)$.

Comment: exactly! thanks a bunch